# Not selecting duplicates rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL code as below

```
SELECT
   Country,
   Region,
   COUNT(Country) AS [Count],
   CASE WHEN  Region IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END AS Category
FROM
    Games
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS (
                (Country, Region) 
                ,(Country)          
            )               
HAVING GROUPING(Region) = 0 OR COUNT(DISTINCT Region) > 0 
ORDER BY
    Country,
    Category,
    Region
```

Result is as below

```
COUNTRY         REGION    Count  Category
-------         -------    ---    -------
UNKNOWN         UNKNOWN    3       0
UNKNOWN         UNKNOWN    3       1
AUSTRIA         NULL       1       0
AUSTRIA         A          1       1
BELGIUM         NULL       1       0
BELGIUM         A          1       1
CZECH REPUBLIC  NULL       3       0
CZECH REPUBLIC  A          1       1
CZECH REPUBLIC  B          1       1
CZECH REPUBLIC  C          1       1
OPPS            OPPS       1       0
OPPS            OPPS       1       1
TURKEY          NULL       6       0
TURKEY          A          1       1
TURKEY          B          1       1
TURKEY          C          1       1
TURKEY          D          1       1
TURKEY          E          1       1
TURKEY          H          1       1
```

I don't want to select duplicate rows according to my example result as below

```
UNKNOWN         UNKNOWN    3       0
OPPS            OPPS       1       0
```

is it possible?

Comment: The canonical way to do this is [distinct](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/distinct.php)

Comment: Sorry @hd1 DISTINCT doesn't  work.

Comment: @Kerberos : please show input and expected output, Someone can suggest a different approach too, if you are open to it.

Comment: Using `MAX(CASE WHEN  Region IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE 1 END) AS Category` can be helpful ;).

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If you are grouping only on `country` and `region`, then `'UNKNOWN'`/`'UNKNOWN'` cannot be duplicated.  The `GROUPING SETS` conditions have nothing to do with this.  Any additional rows they produce would have `NULL` values in one or both of these columns.

So, my only conclusion is that `'UNKNOWN'` is different in the different rows.  You may not see the difference.  One possibility is trailing spaces.  Another is invisible characters.